# Changing img src on click with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to change image when I click on it every time.

I added full path even it's not working.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
   var imageon= document.getElementById("myElement");
 function changeImage(){
 if (imageon.src=="play1.gif"){
 imageon.src="shutdown.png";
    }
 else if (imageon.src== "shutdown.png") {
 imageon.src="play1.gif";
 }
 };
 </script>
```

```html
<img src="shutdown.png" id="myElement" onclick="changeImage();" style="width:95px"></img>
```

Javascript:

```
var pullImage=document.getElementById("change");
function changeImage(){
if (pullImage.src=="C:\Users\Srinivas\Downloads\Compressed\attachments_2\play1.gif") {
    pullImage.src="C:\Users\Srinivas\Downloads\Compressed\attachments_2\stop1.png";

};
if (pullImage.src=="C:\Users\Srinivas\Downloads\Compressed\attachments_2\stop1.png"){
    pullImage.src="C:\Users\Srinivas\Downloads\Compressed\attachments_2\play1.gif";

}
};
```

Comment: Why don't you do `alert(imageon.src);` to figure out the actual content format?

Comment: Which function is not working, The upper one or the Lower one? Why theur are two function with same prototype?

Comment: please define 'not working'. any javascript errors? 404's in network tab of your debugger?

Comment: i think the path is wrong.. because it should be relative to the file.. look in your console and see the path of the picture js doesn't find. to see if your code works try it with an online picture

Comment: use relative path. dont give full path. otherwise you need to change path when you deploy project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your path. I recreated the problem and i alerted the actual source which look like this:

[image: Full Path]

You will either have to give the actual full path. Or you dont use the path as refrence, but a html reference. For example a hidden div with value 1 or 2 - for the used image

```
<div id="imgnumber">1</div>

<script>
var imagediv = document.getElementById("imgnumber");
var imageon= document.getElementById("myImg");
    function changeImage(){
        if (imagediv.innerHTML == "1"){
            imageon.src="b.png";
            imagediv.innerHTML = "2";
        }
        else if (imagediv.innerHTML == "2") {
            imageon.src="a.gif";
            imagediv.innerHTML = "1";
        }
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below javascript and place it anywhere below  tag you are using

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      var imageon= document.getElementById("myElement");
      function changeImage(){
         var filename = imageon.src.replace( /^.*?([^\/]+)\..+?$/, '$1' );
         if (filename=="play1"){
           imageon.src="shutdown.jpg";
         }
          else if (filename== "shutdown") {
             imageon.src="play1.jpg";
         }
      };
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using attr function you can change `src` of image :

```
$("#my_image").attr("src","second.jpg");
```

You can also create event eg. put thumbnail and on clicking load original image:

```
$('#my_image').on({
    'click': function(){
        $('#my_image').attr('src','second.jpg');
    }
});
```

Comment: You can also generate random number, and load image according to that number